# Powershell Script for automatic network recording using vlc player

Tags: powershell, vlc

I'm in a project, where it is now happening everyday to record a videostream from a network source. For this we are utilising the VLC Player as a reasonable tool. For this we go to menu "Open Media" then choose "Network" and enter the ip address e.g. "tcp://192.168.1.200:50000". Then we press convert and select a profile and a filename, which is quite tedious to select all this options several times a day.

Would it be possible to write a powershell script that automizes this task and starts VLC by recording a file name -.vlc inside some kind of predefined folder?

Comment: Have you looked at VLC's [command-line interface](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)?

Comment: @mklement0: What is that? I'll search the internet. Thank you for the hint.